# The "Add to Cart" button will not centre, how can I fix this?

Tags: html, css

I am making some product cards with an "Add to cart" button. Everything else is aligned centred in the card, but the button is somehow to the far right even tho the code says otherwise. What I mean by this is the button is inside the card's div, so I don't know how if there is something wrong in my code or I'm missing a key style element. *I should note my college project is purely website redesign, not development/implementation hence the webpage looks incomplete.* [image: Here is the picture of the product card] I'm trying to get this little blunder outta the way before I add more product cards, filling the page. Also bear in mind I am still new to coding but I'm always learning and improving.

```css
@font-face  {
  Src: url(customfont/Futuristic.ttf);
  Font-family: Future;
  }
@font-face  {
 Src: url(customfont/RobotInvaders.ttf);
 Font-family: Robo;
  }
h1  {
  Font-family: Future; 
  Color: red;
  Text-align: center;
  }
h2  {
  color: blue; 
  text-align: left;
  Font-family: Robo;
  }
.servicesnav nav  {
  Width: 100%;
  Height: 70px;
  Overflow: hidden;
  Background: none;
  }
.servicesnav li  {
  Display: inline;
  Padding-right: 40px;
  }
.servicesnav ul {
  List-style-type: none;
  }
 .servicesnav li a:hover  {
  Background: blue;
  }
.card {
  max-width: 200px;
  Height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  }
.card h3  {
  Color: red;
  }
.price {
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  }
.description  {
  Color: white;
  }
.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  Text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 18px;
  }
.card button:hover {
  Color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Geek Yourself Out" />
    <title>Geek Yourself Out</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GeekYourselfOut.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Services.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
 </head>
  <body>
   <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" width="95"/></a>
    </div>
   <div class="coolname">
      <a href="#"><img src="coolname.jpg" width="105"/></a>
   </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
      <li class="current-page"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="CQ.html">Consultation & Quotes</a></li>
      <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact&nbsp;Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="clientreferrals.html" target="_blank">Client Referrals</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
   <h1>Choose one of these categories to start browsing!    </h1>
   <div class="servicesnav">
     <nav>
       <ul>
       <li><a href="">Physical Products</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Marketing Materials</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Apparel</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Photos</a></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
<h2>Physical Products</h2>
<div class="card">
<img src="ProductService/custom.png" alt="Custom" style="width:100%">
<h3>Custom Product</h3>
<p class="price">$5-$100</p>
<p class="description">Upload your 3D design file(s) and get it printed into a product! No design is too big or small! *Please only upload completed and full-colour 3D design files. We will reject orders of 2D files, unfinished design, or black-and-white.* </p>
<p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="bottom-content">
      <h3>Geek Yourself Out</h3>
      <p>To get some behind-the-scenes action to staying updated on the latest projects, check out these social media links! All follows, likes, comments, and shares are appreciated. </p>
        <div class="socials">
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Geekyourselfout/"><img src="facebook-box-fill.png" alt="Facebook"</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/geekyourselfout/"><img src="instagram-fill.png" alt="Instagram"</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-page">
      <p>copyright &copy;2022 Geek Yourself Out. Designed by Kimmy Vo</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there i try your code but it shows add to cart button in the center. But still if you face issue try to reset the css by using following code in your style.css file:

```
* {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

I also attach screenshot of your code with this where your code shows add to cart button in the center.

[image: Image of your code]

Comment: Hi, your image link is invalid kindly update a new correct one.

Comment: I tried out your reset suggestion but it did not fix the button placement at all. Shall I post my entire HTML and CSS code then?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its issue with any other parent div because when I tried your HTML and CSS on codepen add to cart button is centered.

You can see the codepen I used:- `https://codepen.io/GauravSingh96/pen/JjMEeoQ`

This is the html used:-

```
<div class="card">
<img src="ProductService/custom.png" alt="Custom" style="width:100%">
<h3>Custom Product</h3>
<p class="price">$5-$100</p>
<p class="description">Upload your 3D design file(s) and get it printed into a product! No design is too big or small! *Please only upload completed and full-colour 3D design files. We will reject orders of 2D files, unfinished design, or black-and-white.* </p>
<p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
```

You will have to recheck all the codes from top.